# What is the difference between "has since" and "since then" and which is better here?

Tags: tense, difference

What is the difference between

> The company opened {it’s / its} doors in May 2015, and {has since / since then} finalized all the contracts.

And which is better?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You do not need the apostrophe here in the word "its". In your case it is a possessive pronoun derived from personal pronoun "it". So you must use **its** and not **it's**. **It's** is used when it represents a contraction from **it is**.
About the second part. *Since then finalized* is not very good. *Has since finalized* is much better.
So in my opinion your sentence will be like that:

> The company opened its doors in May 2015 and has since finalized all
>   the contracts.

(Present Perfect indicates a terminated action.)

I removed the comma before *and*. I think it's unnecessary.

Comment: Alex is correct. Don't let the fact that you will find confusion between 'it's' and 'its' all over the web, even by native speakers, deter you.

Comment: "Since then has finalized" would also be grammatically correct.